# How to define absolute position for watermark image?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick, node-imagemagick

My background image will not be straight vertical shape, think of 3d covers, It will have some slope shape. I want to match above image to that coordinates of background image.  Is there any way to define my upper image's **top-left**,**top-right**,**bottom-left** and **bottom-right**?

```
var fs = require('fs'),gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick:true});

    gm('background.png')
    .command('composite')
    .in('-page', '0+0')
    .in('front.png')
    .write('output.png', function(err) {
        if(!err) console.log("Written composite image.");
    });
```

Comment: You can use +distort perspective in ImageMagick with a transparent background (-virtual-pixel), then composite over the use image. I am not familiar with GraphicsMagick, but I assume it has a similar function. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective

Comment: @fmw42 node js gm doesn't support distort. Instead I have used imagemagick command. It works! Anyone who struggles with gm, I suggest you to use imagemagick command. which is mentioned on above comment.